# the usage of open() function in telnetlib in Python

Tags: python, linux, sockets, telnet

I don't quite understand the open() function in telnetlib below, can someone explain for me?

```
def open(self, host, port=0):
        """Connect to a host.

        The optional second argument is the port number, which
        defaults to the standard telnet port (23).

        Don't try to reopen an already connected instance.

        """
        self.eof = 0
        if not port:
            port = TELNET_PORT
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        msg = "getaddrinfo returns an empty list"
    # ---
        for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
            af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res  #???
            try:
                self.sock = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
                self.sock.connect(sa) 
    # ---
            except socket.error, msg:
                if self.sock:
                    self.sock.close()
                self.sock = None
                continue
            break
        if not self.sock:
            raise socket.error, msg
```

From For to Except part, I feel most confused.

Is this function used to telnet? Why no any telnet there?

Comment: Are you having troubles with understanding the implementation of the function (as a newbie you probably should not try) or with using it? In case of the latter, which tutorials have you looked at and why did they not help you? Start with generic tutorials, then read the telnetlib docu.

Comment: Yes, I just learn some basic grammar, but I have to begin to work on fixing a tool, maybe I should learn more on tutorial. so I guess open() is to open a IP with a port, port 23 means telnet, am I right?

Comment: @Daniel.Lin: All this does is open the socket and handle errors. Do you know sockets? You should probably have a look at [socket.getaddrinfo](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo). Put simply, this returns you all information you require to open the socket by looking at the arguments

Comment: @urban: Thank you, I have read socket.getaddrinfo before, and I'm learning the socket now, I think I can understand more after getting to know socket.